# Control problems

Tags: if-statement, lua

I am having a problem with my control statement. I have just started programming.

---

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
answers = {
123,
132,
231,
213,
321,
312
}
outcomes = ( answers[ math.random( #answers ) ] )
print("What is your first guess?")
io.write("Guess#1: \n")
g1 = io.read()
onetwothree()
function onetwothree()
if o = 123 and g1 = 321 then
print("You have no numbers correct")
end
end

os.execute("PAUSE")
```

---

When I run the code in my IDE, it displays this:

```
>lua -e "io.stdout:setvbuf 'no'" "Mastermind.lua" 
lua: Mastermind.lua:25: 'then' expected near '='
>Exit code: 1
```

By the way, line 25, in my code is this:

```
if o = 123 and g1 = 321 then
```

How do I fix this and what is happening.

Comment: Learn how to indent your code correctly. It will save you more than one headache! Moreover posting badly indented code on SO gives the impression that you are lazy and many SO users avoid answering to people perceived as lazy.

Comment: `onetwothree()` was called before it was defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're using `=` for comparison instead of `==`.

Change your condition to:

```
if o == 123 and g1 == 321 then
```